Should questions tagged with "bitcoin-protocol" also be tagged as "protocol"?
The [protocol] tag:

For questions relating to the protocols by which crypto-currencies are
  transferred.

The [bitcoin-protocol] tag:

For questions relating to the protocol by which specifically bitcoins
  are transferred. Also see protocol.

I've got a question which is related to "bitcoin mining pools" and "bitcoin target". But it could also be related to "mining pools" and "targets in general".
As such, do I tag it as both [protocol] and [bitcoin-protocol]?
Or are questions tagged with [bitcoin-protocol] automatically assumed to be under [protocol] tag?

As it is, I would assume that questions tagged with bitcoin-protocol are a subset of protocol.
I think it that I created the bitcoin-protocol in March, but today I am not sure if that made sense: While in the long run the protocols might further distinguish and it would make sense to have a bitcoin-protocol to cater to issues that specifically refer to bitcoin, at this point, the protocols are probably still too similar to have different tags for the bitcoin-protocol and other protocols. 
Perhaps bitcoin-protocol should be merged back into protocol. What do you think?

Yea, I think merging would be great. For example, if someone wants to find out about darkcoin protocol, he could filter by the combined tags [darkcoin] and [protocol].

I want to wait a little bit, in case somebody else also wants to add something. Otherwise I am going to go ahead tomorrow and merge it back into [protocol]
